# Simulating ar(2) model generates an error message

Tags: r, error-handling, time-series, autoregressive-models

I am new to simulation especially when it comes to time series and so I apologize if this question seems too naive. I am trying to understand why simulating this ar(2) model generates an error:

```
arima.sim(list(order = c(2, 0, 0), ar = c(0.7, 0.3)), n = time_n, sd=0.2) 
Error in arima.sim(list(order = c(2, 0, 0), ar = c(0.7, 0.3)), n = time_n,  : 
  'ar' part of model is not stationary
```

Any pointer will be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to theory (e.g. see [here](https://www.bauer.uh.edu/rsusmel/phd/ec2-3.pdf)), in order for an autoregressive model to be stationary, if `r` are the roots of the autoregressive polynomial

```
1 - phi_1 x - phi_2 x ...
```

then

> The linear AR(p) process is strictly stationary and ergodic
> if and only if |rj|>1 for all j, where |rj| is the modulus of the
> complex number rj.

In your case

```r
polyroot(c(1, -0.7, -0.3))
```

gives (1,-3.333)

In fact, this is the actual code within `arima.sim`:

```r
  minroots <- min(Mod(polyroot(c(1, -model$ar))))
    if (minroots <= 1) 
        stop("'ar' part of model is not stationary")
```

Looking at the patterns and being lazy about the math, I suspect that the criterion for AR2 translates to (ph1 + phi2 < 1).